# UICollectionView not responding when CollectionView Cell is Selected

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i make a application that Contain UICollectionview and ImageView when i select UICollectionViewCellImage then  it was Display In UIImageview and i add a UIBUtton in to UIImageView to Back into UICollectionview but when i back to UICollectionview it was not Responding. Please Give me Solution.

My Code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.zoomImage.hidden=TRUE;
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
self.zoomImage.hidden=FALSE;
NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSString *img=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
[self.zoomImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img]];
self.imagecollection.hidden=TRUE;
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
}
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
self.imagecollection.hidden=FALSE;
self.zoomImage.hidden=TRUE;
}
```

Here imagecollection is my UICollectionView and Zoomimage is UIImageView.
if any SolutionPossible then please give me Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% understood the issue. I think, you can try this:

```
self.collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = true.
```

If you have found the solution, please post it. It can be useful